# Trying to build rdiff-backup, getting error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrsync"

Tags: linux, compilation, rsync, librsync, rdiff-backup

I am trying to build the latest version of rdiff-backup on a CentOS 6 x64 box. (linode).

I am getting the error as follows:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrsync

I have searched for a rsync.so file with no results.

I have rsync already installed.  I can't find an rsync-devel package to install with Yum using the standard repositories.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install librsync:

```
yum install librsync-devel
```

Comment: This worked, but my default installation did not have the EPEL-6 repositiory set up yet, thus it could not find package 'librsync-devel'.  I had to install EPEL-6 via instructions at this link first: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F

Comment: Previously, I was trying to build librsync from source since the EPEL-6 was not set up.  The build was successful, but even so the rdiff-backup compiler could not find the library.  What files should have been copied from the librsync build directory to specific directories in my installation in order to fix this without needing the librsync-devel package?